# Using ggplot2: Create faceted scatterplot with scaled and moved density

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot some data as a scatter plot using facet_wrap, while superimposing some information such as a linear regression and the density.
I managed to do all that, but the density values are out of proportion with respect to my points, which is a normal thing since these points are far away. Nevertheless, I'd like to scale and move my density curve so that it is clearly visible; I don't care about it's real values but more about its shape.

Here is an exaggerated minimum working example of what I have:

```
set.seed(48151623)
mydf <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(mean=5,n=100),x2=rnorm(n=100,mean=10),x3=rnorm(n=100,mean=20,sd=3))
mydf$var <- mydf$x1 + mydf$x2 * mydf$x3 
mydf.wide  <- melt(mydf,id.vars='var',measure.vars=c(1:3))
ggplot(data=mydf.wide,aes(x=value,y=var)) +
  geom_point(colour='red') +
  geom_smooth(method='lm') +
  stat_density(aes(x=value,y=..scaled..),position='identity',geom='line') +
  facet_wrap(~variable,scale='free_x')
```

Which results in:
[image: example of current plot]

What I would like resembles to this ugly hack:

```
stat_density(aes(x=value,y=..scaled..*100+200),position='identity',geom='line')
```

Ideally, I would use `y=..scaled..* diff(range(value)) + min(value)` but when I do this I get an error saying that 'value' was not found. I suspect the problem is related to the faceting, but I would prefer to keep my facets.

How can I scale and move the density curve in this case?

[image: cool result but ugly hack]

Comment: The fact that creating a new variable `mx` in `mydf.wide` with the max y value and then passing `y = ..scaled.. * mx` doesn't work seems to me to be if not quite a bug, at the very least unexpected behavior. The only other option I can think of off the top of my head is the old standby: calculate the densities outside of ggplot and store them in a separate data frame.

Comment: Using a separate data.frame for densities is exactly what they do here: https://gist.github.com/alaiacano/1405150 but I haven't been able to make it work for me.

Comment: Based on my tests with your code I would be surprised (and confused) if that code you linked to still worked.

Comment: Yes of course, since that code is for a grid facet. The idea seems nice though, but what I meant is that I couldn't adapt it for my case.

Comment: is this really a good idea though? Why not use facetting, and have the density curves above the scatterplots, with their own y scale? What you're trying to achieve sounds a lot like double axes, which have always been made very hard to obtain, on purpose. The idea, I think, being that two datasets in the same panel shouldn't have a different y scale, because the human perception tends to focus attention on crossing lines, relative slopes, etc. which are meaningless if the scales are different between glyphs.

Comment: @baptiste: I understand that the guidelines of ggplot and most its developers and users is to avoid double axes, but I disagree with that idea. I'm sure there are good publications that support this; I just disagree with the intransigence of not using two axes. Sometimes it can help to transmit a quick idea about my data (in my case the audience knows that a density rarely values around 150-300). I'm sure you know how journals and conferences continue to limit the number of figures, which is authors continue to put two things in the same plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate the answers of everyone, which led me to better understand ggplot underlying mechanisms. I also realize how awkward my requirement is; ggplot is not going to solve my problem.
I managed to do what I wanted not by using ggplot `stat_density` but to directly calculate my densities in another data frame:

```
set.seed(48151623)
mydf <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(mean=5,n=100),x2=rnorm(n=100,mean=10),x3=rnorm(n=100,mean=20,sd=3))
mydf$var <- mydf$x1 + mydf$x2 * mydf$x3 
mydf.wide  <- melt(mydf,id.vars='var',measure.vars=c(1:3))

mydf.densities <- do.call('rbind',lapply(unique(mydf.wide$variable), function(var) {
  tmp <- mydf.wide[which(mydf.wide$variable==var),c('var','value')]
  dfit <- density(tmp$value,cut=0)
  scaledy <-dfit$y/max(dfit$y) * diff(range(tmp$var)) + min(tmp$var)
  data.frame(x=dfit$x,y=scaledy,variable=rep(var,length(dfit$x)))
}))
ggplot(data=mydf.wide,aes(x=value,y=var)) +
  geom_point(colour='red') +
  geom_smooth(method='lm') +
  geom_line(aes(x=x,y=y),data=mydf.densities) +
  facet_wrap(~variable,scale='free_x')
```

(I know that the construction of `mydf.densities` is a bit obfuscated, but I will work on that later).

I'm giving out the bounty to the most voted solution at the end of the day, for your troubles.

[image: The plot I wanted to do]

Answer (score 6):

I suggest to make two plots and combine them with `grid.arrange`:

```
p1 <- ggplot(data=mydf.wide,aes(x=value,y=var)) +
  geom_point(colour='red') +
  geom_smooth(method='lm') +
  facet_wrap(~variable,scale='free_x') +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        plot.margin =       unit(c(1, 1, 0, 0.5), "lines"))

p2 <- ggplot(data=mydf.wide,aes(x=value,y=var)) +
  stat_density(aes(x=value,y=..scaled..),position='identity',geom='line') +
  facet_wrap(~variable,scale='free_x') + 
  theme(strip.background=element_blank(),
        strip.text=element_blank(),
        plot.margin =       unit(c(-1, 1, 0.5, 0.35), "lines"))

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1, p2, heights = c(2,1))
```

[image]

Comment: Also, consider adding a [rug plot](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/geom_rug.html) using `geom_rug`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this completely answers your question, but it was too long to put in a comment, so... In response to your second chunk of code in your question, since you've already defined `x=value`, you can use `x` instead of `value` in your definition of y.

```
stat_density(aes(x=value,y=..scaled..*diff(range(x)) + 
min(x)),position='identity',geom='line')
```

This seems to fix your error and produces the following plot:

[image: faceted scatterplot with density curves on same y-axis]

The only problem is, of course, if you have data with low y-values, then you're still going to overlap your density curves with your scatterplot. But, if this isn't the case, I personally think this is a fairly informative figure, as long as you can communicate effectively that the y axis values aren't important in interpreting the density curves--only the shapes of the curves are important.

Comment: Someone had posted this solution and erased it; I don't know why. In the comments, we discussed that the problem is that the idea was to move the density plot to the range of y, instead of the range of x, which is about [2,26].